# Running scripts from a datastore on Azure Machine Learning Service

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am migrating from Batch AI to the new Azure Machine Learning Service. Previously I had my python scripts on an Azure Files share and those scripts ran directly from there.

In the new service when you create an Estimator you have to provide a source directory and an entry script. The documentation states the source directory is a local directory that is copied to the remote computer.

However, the Estimator constructor also allows you to specify a datastore name that is supposed to specify the datastore for the project share.

To me, this sounds like you can specify a datastore and then the source directory is relative to that however this does not work, it still wants to find the source directory on the local machine.

```
tf_est = TensorFlow(source_directory='./script',
                source_directory_data_store=ds,
                script_params=script_params,
                compute_target=compute_target,
                entry_script='helloworld.py',
                use_gpu=False)
```

Does anybody know if its possible to run a training job using a datastore for execution?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/tutorial-train-models-with-aml#create-an-estimator) it seems like you should be able to pass the datastore directory e.g. with the syntax `ds.path('yourdir').as_mount()` in your `script_params` but I haven't tried with `TensorFlow` yet...